# CSS inject not working with Gulp + Browsersync

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

I'm new in gulp, I used to work with grunt, and I'm having some troubles with gulp now.

The most important of them is the auto CSS inject, that isn't woking and after a lot of time I don't know why. Can anyone help me? And also give me some suggestions about my config? Thanks in advance!

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    clean = require('gulp-clean'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    notify = require('gulp-notify'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    lr = require('tiny-lr'),
    server = lr();


var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('vendors', function() {
  return gulp.src('./assets/js/vendors/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('vendors.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js/'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Vendors task complete' }));
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./assets/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded', }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Sass task complete' }));
});


gulp.task('serve',  function() {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "pageone.dev",
        files: "./assets/css/*.css",
        bsFiles: "./assets/css/*.css"
    });

    gulp.watch('./assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('./assets/js/vendors/**.js', ['vendors']);
    gulp.watch('*.php', './assets/css/*.cs', './assets/js/*.js;').on('change', browserSync.reload);

});


gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'sass']);
```

Answer (score 12):

Sourcemaps!

One of the annoying things that I spent too much time debugging is why browser-sync reloads the whole page instead of injecting CSS changes.

After diving into browser-sync files I found out that there default list for injecting files is set to:

```
injectFileTypes: ["css", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "svg", "gif", "webp"],
```

The thing that might not be very apparent is that if any other file that is not on `injectFileTypes` gets changes the browser will reload. In my case the **extra** files that was changed were the sourcemap files `*.css.map`.

If you don't explicitly tell browsersync to ignore sourcemap files when changing or in the initial config the browser will always reload. There's two ways I believe to do this, one through the `browsersync.stream` method like the following:

```
  // Only stream the matching files. Ignore the rest.
  .pipe(browsersync.stream({match: '**/*.css'}));
```

Or on initializing browsersync like the following through the `files` option with excluding pattern to the sourcemaps `files: ['!**/*.maps.css']`.

I like the first one since I am using browsersync with nodemon as a proxy so I don't really use the files argument and setup my own gulp watch statements.

One other way to do this is to update the `injectFileTypes` option when initializing browsersync, however, I am not sure if the CSS sourcemaps are *injectable*.

I hope this help someone having the same issue!

Comment: `.pipe(browsersync.stream({match: '**/*.css'}));` fixed my issue! Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: You're amazing! You don't know how long time this took me to figure out

Answer (score 1):

I found `browserSync.stream` very unreliable. I'd rather suggest a reload through a watch process:

Kill the line with `browserSync` in your Gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('./assets/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded', }))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'))
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/css/'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Sass task complete' }));
});
```

And add the reload while watching:

```
gulp.task('serve',  function() {

   browserSync.init({
      proxy: "pageone.dev",
      files: "./assets/css/*.css",
      bsFiles: "./assets/css/*.css"
  });

  gulp.watch('./assets/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
  gulp.watch('./assets/js/vendors/**.js', ['vendors']);
  gulp.watch('*.php').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('./assets/js/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('./assets/css/*.css').on('change', browserSync.reload);

});
```

Woah... I saw that you already did this. But there's a type on your CSS files, one "s" is missing:

```
 gulp.watch('*.php', './assets/css/*.cs', './assets/js/*.js;').on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

There's also a semi-colon at your JS files glob, and I'm not sure if you can pass multiple Globs here.
 Try using this lines:

```
  gulp.watch('*.php').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('./assets/js/*.js').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  gulp.watch('./assets/css/*.css').on('change', browserSync.reload);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it was leaving wrong `rel` value in css link. I updated the href to point to css but `rel` was still `stylesheet/less`

The following actually works if you have reference to less.js and browserSync will update the page, but CSS **will not** be updated:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
```

Changing rel to correct `stylesheet` fixes the problem

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was excited when I found this question, but then disappointment after all the previous answers were not what my issue WAS.

I finally tracked it down to the options object I was passing to browser-sync on start. That object was getting the path for the .less file that I setup a gulp.watch on that rebuilt the .css file for the site.

Tracked down that the path to the .less file started with "./src/client..." but browser-sync was getting the file as "src/client..." and although the paths are different and they point to the same file.

Browser-sync was seeing the .less file as changed and therefore refreshing as it's not in the injectable files list.

- Be sure your paths match as pure STRINGS and not just point to the same file.

Hope this might help others who's issues aren't fixed by the above other options to check.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for @import to load css files in the page header. Drupal does this by default to avoid the css file limit in IE (among other reasons). For Drupal, you can use the [Link CSS module](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_css) or do some theming tricks.

Injection worked for me after making this change.